# How to make custom SLES (SuSe Linux Enterprise) Dockerfiles?

Tags: containers, dockerfile

To use a dockerized SLES, you need to use an official base image and run it on a SLES host.

But this does not seem to work out of the box - what needs to be done to build a custom image?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM suse/sles12:latest
RUN zypper ref -s
RUN zypper --gpg-auto-import-keys ref -s
```

Docker build output - image will be created but obviously it is not possible to install any packages because the central repo seems to be not preconfigured.

Vendor documentation: https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/book_sles_docker/data/customizing_pre-build_images.html

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/3 : FROM suse/sles12:latest
 ---> d0f7e807658b
Step 2/3 : RUN zypper ref -s
 ---> Running in 235316f5bbe1
Refreshing service 'container-suseconnect'.
Problem retrieving the repository index file for service 'container-suseconnect':
[container-suseconnect|file:/usr/lib/zypp/plugins/services/container-suseconnect]
Warning: Skipping service 'container-suseconnect' because of the above error.
All services have been refreshed.
Warning: There are no enabled repositories defined.
Use 'zypper addrepo' or 'zypper modifyrepo' commands to add or enable repositories.
 ---> 21e8beb32227
Removing intermediate container 235316f5bbe1
Step 3/3 : RUN zypper --gpg-auto-import-keys ref -s
 ---> Running in 72ba1ad22da8
Refreshing service 'container-suseconnect'.
Warning: Skipping service 'container-suseconnect' because of the above error.
All services have been refreshed.
Warning: There are no enabled repositories defined.
Use 'zypper addrepo' or 'zypper modifyrepo' commands to add or enable repositories.
Problem retrieving the repository index file for service 'container-suseconnect':
[container-suseconnect|file:/usr/lib/zypp/plugins/services/container-suseconnect]
 ---> 6426e55c2d87
Removing intermediate container 72ba1ad22da8
Successfully built 6426e55c2d87
```

UPD. While this one is working:

```
 docker run -it suse/sles12 bash -c "zypper -n ref -s"
 Adding repository 'SLES12-Debuginfo-Pool for sle-12-x86_64' ...[done]
 .....
```

UPD. Finally, the following worked for me: run a container, install everything there and finally commit the container to a new image (`docker commit container-id image`).

Comment: As your log say: `Use 'zypper addrepo' or 'zypper modifyrepo' commands to add or enable repositories.` before your first RUN command ??

Comment: @Tensibai update - same docker run statement works however; what's the difference?

Comment: That's not the same statement `bash -c "zypper -n ref -s"` is **not** the same as `zypper ref -s`. Running with -it make the container interactive (gets a tty, where a dockerfile doesn't). So there's plenty of differences between your two tests. Considering this is a pay product question, the question would probably be better directed to Suse's support than a community thing.

Comment: this is what I am thinking whether this is specific issue to the enterprise version.

Comment: Considering your working exemple, I'm tempted to guess it's more related to some env variable loaded by bash or the presence of a tty in your interactive exemple, you may try `docker run suse/sles12 "zypper -n ref -s"`to better reproduce what is in the dockerfile and then a `docker logs <container>` to see what it says

Answer (score 1):

As @Tensibai already indicated in one of the comments, some packages are missing:

```
Use 'zypper addrepo' or 'zypper modifyrepo' commands to add or enable repositories.
```

Either use `zypper addrepo` or `zypper modifyrepo` in your dockerfile to solve the issue.

Comment: I consider adding repos by hand is not a must if same docker run statement works, see update